# Does this SE have a ban on Avengers: Endgame questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I would like to ask for something regarding the movie... but so as not to spoil the others that have not yet seen it, does this SE created a ban on MCU *Avengers: Endgame* questions?

Comment: In short, no! Just keep the title spoiler free and the rest is fine. People should read the question at their own risk.

Comment: @AJ so.. i can ask anything?

Comment: As long as it fits the [site scope](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), yes you can!

Comment: Suggestion: You can block/ignore certain tags from appearing in your feed. Because I have yet to see Endgame and I definitely WILL be seeing Endgame, I simply added it to my list of ignored tags. I also blocked Game Of Thrones questions, because they overload the page and I don't watch that show. Simply look at the right side of your page on the main M&TV page. You'll see a button for "Ignored Tags". Click that. Click the Add button, type in "Endgame" and select the tag. Boom. No more spoilers for you!

Answer (score 7):

Why would there be such a ban?

***Avengers: Endgame* is a film and this site is for questions about films.** A blanket ban on questions about a film, especially one likely to be of high public interest, would be directly counter to the principles of knowledge-gathering that are the very foundation of this site.

If it's spoilers you're afraid of, make sure to avoid spoilers in the question title (but also don't just replace names with "this guy" or "[SPOILER]", make sure to provide reasonable question titles).

But everything beyond that is really not our resposibility to care for. We can't protect people who would click random links on the internet and read entire pararaphs only to suddenly wake up after minutes and realize they should have stopped reading about 500 words earlier. Nor should we ban entire questions on a topic of interest for that sole reason.