# Can spoilers be removed from the HNQ?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

[Considering clearly the goal is to spoil the movie for people who haven't seen it,](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1788/9168) can we at least [hide these posts from the HNQ list](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99651/how-did-captain-america-manage-to-do-this)? Or maybe hide the entire site if the current enforced policy is to include spoilers for new releases. So far my impression was that question posts would also include spoilers, but on the linked post a mod pro-actively made the post a spoiler for people who didn't see the movie.

Or alternatively include the title of the movie in the title of the question so people can ignore the question if it's for a new release.

Comment: *"Considering clearly the goal is to spoil the movie for people who haven't seen it"* - Either you're missing a negation in that sentence or I'm not sure where you gather this from and this would sound quite polemic and paint quite a strange light on the tone of your meta question and anyone's willingness to take it serious.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I meant that after two users edited the post to hide the spoilers from the question a moderator pro-actively edited the post to make sure it would include spoilers for people coming from the HNQ list. I am fairly sure that fits with the sentence "*Considering clearly the goal is to spoil the movie for people who haven't seen it*". There was no way in the linked question to know it was about the new movie and per the linked meta post "Once you're in the question body, it's fair game.".

Comment: I don't mean to be negative, but yes, I am somewhat irritated that I 1) got a plot point from a movie spoiled and 2) that when I tried to help anybody else from going through that it gets reverted back. And yes, I thought it would be thus perfectly reasonable to request that these questions and/or this entire site would be removed from the HNQ list, but maybe I should post that on meta.stackexchange.com rather than here~  I dunno.

Comment: There *are* no people coming form the HNQ list and not wanting spoilers, since the question obviously talks about Captain America. If you think some HNQ about Cap apearing on the *Endgame* release date is *actually* about *Civil War* you're...a little too uncareful for the level of vigilance with which you allegedly try to avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, our current enforced policy is to ***not* include spoilers for *any* releases**. However, this only extends to *question titles*, since these are unavoidable. A question body will naturally talk about a film's content and hiding entire swathes of the question's very essence is completely counter to the knowledge-driven philosophy that is the very foundation of this site. You *can* use spoiler blocks in the question body *if* you [**don't use them excessively**](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/49) and your question still **makes sense without everything that's hidden** behind a spoiler block. If that is not the case, don't be too surprised if they get removed for the sake of readability.

With this out of the way, let's get to the matter of the HNQ. Since **spoilers *are actively removed* from question titles**, this alleviates much of the problems of spoilers possibly appearing in that list. I acknowledge that questions might not always start out with spoiler-free titles and it can take a few minutes for our helpful editors to fix them. Unfortunately, a question can get hot quite fast and there's not (yet) a delay for new questions built into the hotness algorithm. However, the title should get fixed eventually. If you can't edit the question title yourself because, e.g. you haven't seen the movie and are afraid to stay on the question for much longer, you can also flag it for moderator attention. But more often than not, other users will likely see and fix it beforehand anyway.

Another problem might be that people don't know the question is about a new release. That's another reason why it's important **not to create nonsense titles like "why did this character do that?"**, which help *noone*. In general, film titles in question titles are not really necessary, but they aren't prohibited either if they don't hinder reading flow. I left, e.g. the word *Endgame* in some of the recent titles so people know what the question is about. But **if you click on a question that's obviously about Captain America when you're trying to avoid spoilers for *Endgame*, not even the Infinity Gauntlet can help you anymore**. We *cannot* and *will not* protect users from their own curiosity. If you *want* to know something, please don't complain afterwards that you...learned something.

As to removing the entire site from the HNQ, I'm afraid that's not going to happen. We will ***not* remove the site for *everyone*** just because *some* users are unable to control their own curiosity, that's not too far from downright [disallowing the very topic itself](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4469/49). You *can*, however control the visibility of the HNQ list for *yourself*, by a corresponding setting in your user profile. If you want to go that far for avoiding spoilers is *your own* decision, though.