# Could we wait for a while before asking a question about the film that just came out?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Fortunately, I managed to cover questions about [avengers-endgame](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-endgame) with my hand before I could see it.

I'm actually a bit angry at those who ask questions about the new film immediately after they have just seen it. And I feel sorry for mods who see spoilers every day. I suggest waiting for, like a week after the movie came out, so that almost everyone could see the new movie(*BTW, in my country Endgame comes out April 29th*) and wouldn't see spoilers. I think that would really improve the site and don't scare off those, who don't like spoilers.

**<sup>I'm not talking only about Endgame; about any new movie.</sup>**

Comment: There are mechanisms in place (ignoring tags) that you can use to hide questions on a certain movie.

Comment: I have sympathies for people who are spoiled by Hot Network Questions - but little sympathy for someone who comes to the site when they are aware they may see spoilers here.  I hid question about Endgame from myself and was fully aware that coming here over the last few days was my own choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, we cannot!

As detailed in the discussions to a [similar question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4469/49), waiting with asking your question just out of a fear of spoilers is exactly the kind of anti-information philosophy that goes against everything SE stands for.

Also, *how* much time is enough? Who says that a week is the right amount of time to wait? What happens when someone *does* ask a question? Do we delete it? Do we close it? Do we tell the user to come back next week? **The question is for all intents and purposes on-topic and appropriate for this site, so it gets asked!** Artificial time limitations would just seem ridiculous and not help the site at all. Instead **people go *elsewhere* with their questions and answers**. They'll do the hell and sit around on it for days.

There are better ways to protect people from spoilers while *not* shutting off any kind of dicussion at the same time and these things are already done, primarily not putting spoilers in question titles.

On the botton line, what you propose is exactly the *opposite* of dealing with nowadays' internet spoiler paranoia in a reasonable and sane way, because it's basically **giving in to the madness and shutting off useful and informative discussions on a topic people are *clearly* interested in** on the sole basis that a select few people just don't have the impulse control not to click on a question about a film they don't want to read anything about.

And even more so, you have absolutely ***no right and no reason* to be angry at someone asking a question about something he wants to know from a film he just saw**. It is *not* their fault and if *you* had seen the film, I have strong doubts you'd hold back with your questions much, seeing how you yourself tried to ask myriads of *Endgame* questions *weeks if not months* before the film was even released. This anger is entirely counter-productive and misdirected and I'd *urge* you to overcome it rather than blaming everyone else who has seen the movie except for you.